# Torchlight 2 - Does Focus affect skills which has elemental components?

Tags: torchlight-2

Does Focus adds to damage from elemental skills, such as the Berserker's Shadow Burst or Frost Breath?

Comment: I know focus affects stuff like "+50-60 poison damage", but I'm also curious if it affects the "50% of weapon dps as poison damage" kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If a skill says `deals X amount of Y as Ice/Fire/Poison/Shadow damage` or just plain: `deals X amount of Ice/Fire/Poison/Shadow damage` your **Focus** stat will be used in the calculation of your damage.

So if you're going to use a lot of skills that mention Elemental Damage, it makes sense to invest in the Focus stat. Even so, my Outlander uses only skills with elemental damage and *only* has Focus points invested.

It's also easy to verify this (if you don't mind using the console on a test character).
Just use `Frost Breath` on the dummy, my level 2 hit for about `6` damage on average. I then gave him 200 more Focus (= 100% more elemental damage) and he hit for about `12` on average.